# How to remove authentication from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the class below which uses antMatchers to remove authentication from a public endpoint.
However the public endpoint is also being blocked and I keep getting a HTTP/1.1 401.
Can anyone please help me to spot what's wrong below?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UsersService usersService;

@Autowired
private UsersRepository usersRepo;    

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder()
{
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()                
        .and().addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter());        
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(usersService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}

private AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), 
     usersService);
    return filter;
}
```

}

---------------update 1-------------------

I tried with http POST, using curl and I get back the below.
It seems like the request is caught somewhere but not in the controller I am trying to hit:

```
$ curl -X POST  http://localhost:8083/public -H 'Content-Type:     
application/json' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -d '{  
"email":"test2@test.com", "password":"12345678" }' -v

*   Trying ::1:8083...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8083 (#0)
> POST /user HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8083
> User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> cache-control: no-cache
> Content-Length: 51
>
* upload completely sent off: 51 out of 51 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 401
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=72AB25425322A17AE7014832D25284FD; Path=/;    
HttpOnly
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 31 Mar 2020 11:36:10 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: Did you using POST method to access that URL `/public`? Or you are accessing to that URL via browser which will user GET method?

Comment: I tried with http POST without luck using curl as per update 1 above.

Comment: You can check the startup logs and you should see one or more proxy filters being created, these are the spring security filters. You might want to update with these logs to help identify the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to override the WebSecurity method to completely ignore your /public path from Spring Security processing.

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/public/**");
}
```

Comment: I updated it but still getting a 401:

    @ Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/**");
        }    

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {        
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable();     
        }

Comment: sure that you overrode the *WebSecurity* method, not the *HttpSecurity* method?

Comment: 100% sure, I even removed HttpSecurity Override

Comment: could you try changing the antMacher to "/public", in the WebSecurity method.

Comment: I just tried again but still getting a 401. I removed HttpSecurity Override.
    @ Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public");
    }

Maybe Am I missing something in the controller for /public?

I only have two annotations below at the class level:
@ Configuration
@ EnableWebSecurity

An one annotation at the function level:
@PostMapping("/public")

Comment: Two things: 1. remove the HttpMethod from the antMatcher, so no more POST. Shouldn't have an effect, but still.

Comment: 2. Are you sure that Security class in the same package or below your @SpringBootApplication class? Otherwise, it won't get scanned in.

Comment: Otherwise, this doesn't make sense :D

Comment: it worked, the package with SecurityConfig was not seen by Spring. I added a @Componnet and worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know without seeing all of your code, but I suspect that this has nothing to do with the `authorizeRequests()` portion of your configuration. Instead, I suspect it is the `AuthenticationFilter` which is attempting to authenticate the request because you have included credentials in the request. The default is to try to authenticate anytime the `AuthenticationConverter` returns credentials. Then  `AuthenticationFailureHandler` will respond with HTTP 401 if invalid credentials are provided.

To resolve this, you can remove the credentials from your request. Alternatively, you can limit which requests `AuthenticationFilter` are invoked on by setting the requestMatcher. Something like this would limit to processing `POST` to `/authenticate`:

```
private AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    final AuthenticationFilter filter = new AuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), 
     usersService);
    filter.setRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/authenticate", "POST"));
    return filter;
}
```